# $\phi: S_1\rightarrow S_2$ to be surjective, along with $(I)$ is enough to conclude $\phi$ is a local isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two regular surfaces. An **isometry** is a diffeomorphism $\phi: S_1\rightarrow S_2$ such that

$$\langle d\phi_p(v_1), d\phi_p(v_2)\rangle=\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$$ for every $p\in S_1$ and $v_1, v_2\in T_p S_1$. A **local isometry** from $S_1$ to $S_2$ is a differentiable map $\phi: S_1\rightarrow S_2$ such that for every $p\in S_1$ there are open sets $V_1\subset S_1$, with $p\in V_1$, $V_2\subset S_2$ such that $\phi: V_1\rightarrow V_2$ is an isometry.

The notes which I'm following states that if $\phi: S_1\rightarrow S_2$ is a **surjective** differentiable map such that

$$\langle d\phi_p(v_1), d\phi_p(v_2)\rangle=\langle v_1, v_2\rangle\tag{I}$$

for every $p\in S_1$ and $v_1, v_2\in T_p S_1$, then $\phi$ is a local isometry.

I believe there is something missing, maybe the correct hypothesis should be $\phi$ is a **surjective submersion**, shouldn't it?

I think so, because $(I)$ implies $d\phi_p$ is injective for every $p\in S_1$. Under the hypotehesis $\phi$ is a submersion, $d\phi_p$ is surjetive, hence $d\phi_p$ is an isomorphism for every $p\in S_1$ and it is possible to apply the inverse function theorem in order to conclude $\phi$ is a local isometry.

In short, $\phi: S_1\rightarrow S_2$ to be surjective, along with $(I)$ is enough to conclude $\phi$ is a local isometry?

Comment: Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ have the same dimension, $d\phi_p$ is injective if and only if its surjective.

Comment: Why do $S_1$ and $S_2$ have the same dimension?

Comment: I understood "regular surface" as "two-dimensional submanifold", isn't that what is meant?

Comment: That's correct, I was thinking about general manifolds, my bad!